# How to read values from _config.yml file in Jekyll hook

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll, hook

I am trying to read specific part of `_config.yml` in my Jekyll hook method something like this:

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :after_init do
    lm = Jekyll.config("latex-macros")
end
```

in `_config.yml` is:

```
latex-macros:
  - ["\\RR", "\\mathbb{R}"]
```

so in `lm` variable should be:

```
[["\\RR", "\\mathbb{R}"]]
```

---

I already tried to to use `Jekyll.configuration({})["latex-macros"]` and it kinda worked but it ignores `--config` terminal option and reads file everytime it is called. This makes it unusable for me.

---

I also tried

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :after_init do
    lm = context.registers[:site].config["latex-macros"]
end
```

but it throws run time error:

> katex.rb:8:in '<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method 'context' for main:Object (NameError)

---

My question is, how to read `_config.yml` values in jekyll hook properly? How do I fix second method?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing this from top of my head since it's been a long time I used Jekyll. You need to pass `site` variable into hook.

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :after_init do |site|
  # Access using site.config[key]
  puts site.config['latex-macros']
end
```